# Node update 12.16.3 -> 14.17.0 unsuccessful after nvm and cache clear

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nvm

NODE ISSUE No Resolve!
I think possible PATH misdirect .... not sure
Good evening everyone,
I have tried and searched various ways to resolve this. This problem has plagued me for weeks and I have tried and searched most everything I can. Im not sure if my node isnt being updated globally.my issue is the following: Updating node and clearing cache.
[image: terminal error]
In my terminal i am running:
npx create-react-app project_ts --template typescript

Returns error:
You are running Node 12.16.3.
Create React App requires Node 14 or higher.
Please update your version of Node.
I then proceeded to:
Use NVM: nvm install version 14.7.0

```
Run nvm use v14.7.0 or nvm use v16.17.0
    NVM DOES UPDATE MY NODE VERSION...BUT :
     nvm -v -> shows i am still running v12.16.3.  *I restarted IDE -VSCODE...nothing.
```

proceeded to clean cache:

Sudo npm cache clean -f
Sudo npm install -g n
Sudo stable
AND SUCCESS, BUT...
Upon running code again same issue. Any solutions. Ideally I'd like to resolve this permanently. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to run `nvm use [your version]`.

Running `nvm use v14.7.0` or `nvm use v16.17.0` should resolve your issue.

You can install several versions at the same time with nvm. When you install a new one, it doesn't switch the default version automaticaly, you have to choose it afterward.

That said, using `nvm use [version]` is temporary and will only have effect on the current shell and its sub-processes.

To change your node version globaly, you must run `nvm alias default [version]`.

Comment: I actually did that * will add to my initial message, am actually thinking my PATH isn't set correctly on my mac, would you know how to change the PATH...

Comment: @HyperLuminous What is the result of the command `which node` ?

Comment: /Users/tonio/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.3/bin/node
/usr/local/bin/node

Comment: Have you tried to define a new node `default` version with `nvm alias default [the version you want]` ?

Comment: Your problem can happen if installed node from brew without using NVM at a point in time. Check your .bashrc or .bash_profile for `PATH` changes.

Comment: so upon looking at the node i noticed that zsh node is running v14.17.0 and the other is running on v12.13.0 ....could this be the error?  I appreciate you assisting

Comment: when i do the nvm alias default will it install globally or only for the project? should I run this in another folder on the terminal?

Comment: Using `nvm alias default [version]` will change the global node version when running `node ...`. Using only `node use [version]` is temporary and restricted to the current shell and its subprocesses.

Comment: RESOLVED!! I REALLY APPRECIATE IT!! CHEERS !